# Fill Data In Existing PDF Form Using Typscript

Tags: node.js, typescript, pdf

I'm trying to fill a form inside an existing PDF using typescript, so far I had no success using `pdf-lib`

```
    const formPdfBytes = await axios.get(formUrl, {
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
    });

    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes.data);

    const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
    const nameField = form.getTextField("CharacterName 2");
    nameField.setText("Mario");
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
```

No errors are showing up, but when I open the PDF it is still empty

Comment: if you debug your code, are all of those data structures populated? `formPdfBytes`, `pdfDoc`, `nameField`, `pdfBytes`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `formPdfBytes`, `pdfDoc`, `nameField`, `pdfBytes` are populated but i don't think with the right fields for `pdf-fill` to use

Comment: If you put some static text in your template PDF file, does it appear in the output file?

Comment: This code should work. Issue might be in your `formPdfBytes.data` coming from request.